# Verify a list of date string is sorted

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of date string in UTC:

```
list = ['2021-11-11T22:23:44.960Z', '2021-11-11T22:23:37.937Z', '2021-11-11T22:23:34.687Z', '2021-11-11T22:22:40.670Z']
```

How do I verify that this list is sorted by date correctly?

Comment: A nice property of this format is that its lexicographical order corresponds to the timestamp order.

Comment: compare the list to a sorted list, or since you're sorting it anyway, just return the sorted list

Answer (score 0):

The easiest:

```
lst == sorted(lst)
```

But for a longer list that might be unsorted, you should opt for a linear and short-circuiting logic:

```
from itertools import pairwise

all(a <= b for a, b in pairwise(lst))
```

Or in Python <= 3.9:

```
all(a <= b for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]))
```

All of this uses the fact that timestamps chronological order corresponds to their lexicographical order.